# How to stop windows defender in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have windows 10 installed on my machine, but I didn't have `gpedit.msc`. So i installed it using the batch file. Now I am going to local group policy editor:

```
Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Defender SmartScreen
```

I can't see windows defender option. Even in Windows Defender SmartScreen, there is no option for disabling.

Some body please guide me how to stop windows defender in windows 10.
 Right now windows defender is running because when I tried to run Geth , I got a message from windows defender 'Don't run'.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the answer but if you know the app is not harmful, you should be able to see "more info" link and still be able to click and run the app.

I would personally prefer not to disable Windows defender.

[image]